# localforage not work in build

Tags: typescript, localforage

I'm using localforage in my code:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import * as LocalForage from 'localforage';
import { ThfStorageConfig } from './thf-storage-config.interface';
```

but when execute `npm run build` the file .d.ts, not contains the import of `localforage`.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ThfStorageConfig } from './thf-storage-config.interface';
```

just in version 1.4.0 of localforage I have success.

My compiled app shows the error `“Cannot find module 'localforage'”` :(

Comment: Is the absence of the import in the `.d.ts` file causing a problem?  TypeScript may be removing imports that are not used by any of the declarations in the `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem with the absence of the import in the .d.ts file because if this import is missing, my compiled app shows the error “Cannot find module 'localforage'”

Comment: That's strange.  What code is that error reported on?  Please add it to the question.  If you manually add the import to the `.d.ts`, does the error go away?  You can run `tsc` with the `--traceResolution` flag to get more information about module resolution.